# Pentaho Set Variable Exception

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've got this doubt about Pentaho set variable step. This is my ktr configuration:

[image]

I'm checking if there are bad records to report. I'm using a sequence to keep the count. After that I'm preparing a document with this errors to be sent just it the counter is greater than zero.

For the kjb father I am using this configutation to check the quantity of errors:

[image]

However when I execute the process, for the ktr I'm getting this message:

> Set Variables 2.0 - Set variable NumberOfErrors to value [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LS7v.png)
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: **Only 1 input row
>   was expected to set the variables and at least 2 were received.**
>           at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.setvariable.SetVariable.processRow(SetVariable.java:96)
>           at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2019/02/04 18:56:36 - Set Variables 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from
>   2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Unexpected error 2019/02/04
>   18:56:36 - Set Variables 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build
>   8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 2019/02/04 18:56:36
>   - Set Variables 2.0 - **Only 1 input row was expected to set the variables and at least 2 were received**. 2019/02/04 18:56:36 - Set
>   Variables 2.0 - 2019/02/04 18:56:36 - Set Variables 2.0 -       at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.setvariable.SetVariable.processRow(SetVariable.java:96)
>   2019/02/04 18:56:36 - Set Variables 2.0 -       at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62) 2019/02/04
>   18:56:36 - Set Variables 2.0 -       at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

And the variable with the errors is equal to zero even when I know that there are some bad records.

[image]

How can I configure the set variable step in the proper way in order to set the value of this variable?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you are seeing is telling you that **Set Variables step only accepts streams containing a single row**.

In case your stream contains many rows this step will throw an error.

To solve your issue you could try aggregating the rows using **Group By** step so that you can aggregate all your rows into a single one which is containing the count field.

After that your Set Variables step will receive only 1 input row and the variable will be successfully set in the parent job.

Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Excellent!! It was very useful. For the records, in my case I had to had a constant instead of the sequence step, and then with the group by I just count the total number of row for that constant.